# Can AdvancedDataGrid automatically detect AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, advanceddatagrid

I was trying the example from this link: [Adobe Flex 4 * Creating column groups](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7bf3.html)

The data is

```
import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            [Bindable]
            private var dpHierarchy:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
                {Region:"Southwest", Territory:"Arizona", 
                    Territory_Rep:"Barbara Jennings", 
                    Revenues:{Actual:38865, Estimate:40000}}, 
                {Region:"Southwest", Territory:"Arizona", 
                    Territory_Rep:"Dana Binn", 
                    Revenues:{Actual:29885, Estimate:30000}},  
                {Region:"Southwest", Territory:"Central California", 
                    Territory_Rep:"Joe Smith", 
                    Revenues:{Actual:29134, Estimate:30000}},  
                {Region:"Southwest", Territory:"Nevada", 
                    Territory_Rep:"Bethany Pittman", 
                    Revenues:{Actual:52888, Estimate:45000}},  
                {Region:"Southwest", Territory:"Northern California", 
                    Territory_Rep:"Lauren Ipsum", 
                    Revenues:{Actual:38805, Estimate:40000}}, 
                {Region:"Southwest", Territory:"Northern California", 
                    Territory_Rep:"T.R. Smith", 
                    Revenues:{Actual:55498, Estimate:40000}},  
                {Region:"Southwest", Territory:"Southern California", 
                    Territory_Rep:"Alice Treu", 
                    Revenues:{Actual:44985, Estimate:45000}}, 
                {Region:"Southwest", Territory:"Southern California", 
                    Territory_Rep:"Jane Grove", 
                    Revenues:{Actual:44913, Estimate:45000}}
            ]);


<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            // Import the data used by the AdvancedDataGrid control. 
            include "SimpleFlatData.as";
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="myADG"
        dataProvider="{dpFlat}"
        width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:groupedColumns>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Region"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Territory"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Territory_Rep"
                headerText="Territory Rep"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup headerText="Revenues">    
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Actual"/>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Estimate"/>
            </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup>    
        </mx:groupedColumns>
   </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
</s:Application>
```

Here, we have to define the `AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup` to get define the grouped columns.

I was trying if AdvancedDataGrid can automatically detect the columns based on the JSON data. I tried with the following code:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="inboxDg"
    designViewDataType="flat"
    editable="true"
    dataProvider="{dpHierarchy}"
    width="100%" height="100%">

</mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

Using this code, AdvancedDataGrid automatically detects the column names and the data. But it fails to create nested columns for `Revenues`. Ideally it should create 2 sub-columns for it as `Actual` and `Estimate`, but it created only one column and the shows data as `[object Object]`
[image: AdvancedDataGrid with auto-detect columns]

Is there any way to make AdvancedDataGrid to create the nested columns automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data isn't flat, and just because you put it in a group doesn't mean it will subgroup it.  The dataField property cannot use dot notation within that, so you've got 2 options, use the labelFunction property, or create a flat data model (I personally prefer the latter).

To do this:

```
private var dpHierarchy:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
                {Region:"Southwest", Territory:"Arizona", 
                    Territory_Rep:"Barbara Jennings", 
                    ActualRevenue:38865,
                    EstimateRevenue:40000}, 
                {Region:"Southwest", Territory:"Arizona", 
                    Territory_Rep:"Dana Binn", 
                    ActualRevenue:38865,
                    EstimateRevenue:40000},  
                {Region:"Southwest", Territory:"Central California", 
                    Territory_Rep:"Joe Smith", 
                    ActualRevenue:38865,
                    EstimateRevenue:40000},  
               etc....
            ]);
```

And then your grid:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="myADG"
        dataProvider="{dpFlat}"
        width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:groupedColumns>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Region"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Territory"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Territory_Rep"
                headerText="Territory Rep"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup headerText="Revenues">    
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="ActualRevenue"/>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="EstimateRevenue"/>
            </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup>    
        </mx:groupedColumns>
   </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

You can also look up using a labelFunction if you'd like, but that seemed more complex than it needs to be.  And lastly I feel I should note that you should set the label property manually on your columns and adhere to coding standards for your data (camelCase).  It just makes things a bit cleaner :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the problem is, data will be created using another system and it is decided that it will be in the nested format. So, creating flat model is out of question. :( Can we modify the AdvancedDataGrid in such a way that it would interpret the nested *object* as nested column?

Comment: Even if the data is created using another system doesn't mean you can't interpret it and add it to a data model of your choosing.  If that seems too much work, you can always look into [labelFunctions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/advancedDataGridClasses/AdvancedDataGridColumn.html#labelFunction) or even use custom [item renderers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS03d33b8076db57b9-23c04461124bbeca597-8000.html)